# how to left align tootip text in bootstrap--4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The text in the tooltip in bootstrap 4 is center-aligned.
How do you left-align it?
And how do you justify it?
Looking for CSS approach.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ipse Epicurus fortasse redderet, ut Sextus Peducaeus, Sex. Si quae forte-possumus. Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi. Traditur, inquit, ab Epicuro ratio neglegendi doloris. Deinde dolorem quem maximum?">
            Tooltip
          </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/RBrnkGUv7o

Answer (score 4):

Use the `data-html` attibute to customize the text. Use `text-left` or `text-justify` to align it...

https://www.bootply.com/TRrXmm3ROD

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
       data-toggle="tooltip" 
       data-html="true" 
       data-placement="top" title="<div class='text-justify'>tooltip text here</div>">
       Tooltip
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem. That's a possible approach. Still looking for a CSS approach :)

Comment: It's already been answered before. Target `.tooltip-inner` in CSS: https://www.bootply.com/MOwGKP9ylv

Comment: Highly appreciated!!